# How are both Jyggalag and Peryite the Daedric Prince of order?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion, the-elder-scrolls-series

I've played Skyrim through several times (as a good guy and a bad guy) and while I'm waiting for the next game, I decided to play Oblivion.  I'm really impressed with the continuity between the two games.  But one thing is really bugging me; in Skyrim, Peryite is the Daedic prince of order and tasks, however in the Shivering Isles expansion of Oblivion, Jyggalag is the Daedric prince of order.  What's up with that?

Comment: If you have this question, just keep playing, all will be revealed.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I think it's better to leave [oblivion] in the question. I believe Jyggalag only appeared in TES IV: Oblivion, and does not appear and isn't mentioned in the other TES games.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Jyggalag's case, I think that "order" refers to logical deduction and determinism. This is not unreasonable considering that his Great Library contained formulae that allowed him to [predict all events before it happened](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Dyus).

According to the Librarian, Dyus:

> The great library was the height of logic and deduction. Contained
>   within its walls were the logical prediction of every action ever
>   taken by any creature, mortal or Daedric. Every birth. Every death.
>   The rise of Tiber Septim. The Numidium. Everything. All predicted with
>   the formulae found within Jyggalag's library.

When the jealous Daedra cursed Jyggalag [to live in opposition to all he stood for](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Jyggalag), they made him the Prince of Madness which is the opposite of logical deduction. In Shivering Isles, Dyus mentions that Sheogorath burned the library because it was the anti-thesis of his new beliefs in personal choice:

> When Sheogorath discovered the library he had it burned, insisting
>   that it was an abomination and that personal choice defied logical
>   prediction.

Thus, I think that the Lore strongly suggests that Jyggalag is the Daedra of Order in the sense of Logical Deduction and determinism.

Regarding Peryite, there are two main in-game sources of information on the Daedra:

Firstly, we have [On Oblivion by Morias Zenon](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:On_Oblivion)

> ...Molag Bal elects the employment of other daedra, and Boethiah
>   inspires the arms of mortal warriors. **Peryite's sphere seems to be
>   pestilence**, and Vaernima's torture.
>
> In preparation for the next instalment [sic] in this series, I will be
>   investigating two matters that have intrigued me since I began my
>   career as a Daedra researcher. ...

Secondly we have [The Book of Daedra](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:The_Book_of_Daedra)

> Peryite, whose sphere is the ordering of the lowest orders of Oblivion, known as the Taskmaster.

Neither of them indicate that he's a Daedra of "Order" or that "Order" is part of his sphere. Rather `The Book of Daedra` makes him sound more like a foreman who manages and "orders" the lesser Daedra around. This is the reason why the primary sources are quick to elaborate that whatever ordering Peryite does is more akin to that of a "Taskmaster".

Notice that in the original text, they add emphasis to the fact that he's a "Taskmaster" by capitalizing the word, but do not do the same for "ordering". This is done to illustrate what his main function is and how he's different from Jyggalag.

Thus, even if we choose to believe that Peryite is a Daedra of Order, it seems clear to me that his sphere of "Order" is distinct from that of Jyggalag's.

Of course, if this is still unacceptable, we could take the cop-out route and simply claim that Peryite took over his Lord of Order position after he became the Prince of Madness! Since Jyggalag was [cursed before recorded history](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Jyggalag), this explanation isn't contradicted by any in-game manuscripts.

Comment: Nice use of primary sources! Seems the wikis aren't quite accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion here. With so many Princes it is sometimes easy to forget.

Peryite, also known as the Taskmaster, is the Daedric Prince whose spheres are order and pestilence.

Whereas Jyggalag is the Daedric Prince of Order.

[Source 1 : Peryite](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Peryite)

[Source 2 : Jyggalag](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Shivering:Jyggalag)

Comment: That... really doesn't clear it up. Even after reading those links ([and more](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Jyggalag)), I'm still with the asker on this one: how can they be Daedric Princes whose domains are *both* order?

Comment: @One-One I thought that they missed something too, except that the continuity is so "tight" everywhere else.

Comment: Reading the lore, is it possible that Peryite gained the spehere of order when Jyggalag was stuck in the cycle of destruction with Sheogorath? As otherwise there would only be a Daedra of Order for short periods, once per era.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, this is a case of the everso common homonym in the english language.

Peryite is a foreman, a person who orders(gives a command) around his daedra and micromanaging his sphere and the rest of Mundus with minions.

Jyggalag, is the master of Order(structure, sequence, pattern, method, Relativity) and he is the all knowing recorder on time-space and existence.

This sadly is why he was cursed... Hermaus Mora didn't like the fact that Jyggalag could see his oh so valuable information so he banded the rest of the daedra against Jyggalag by making them think that they were in danger of having their sphere conquered or , in the case of Bolag Mal that they could enjoy messing with another prince. So he was cursed... then the rest of the story is known through playing the shivering isles DLC Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 0):

Peryite is more of the "balance/equality in the universe" type of Order.
Jyggalag is more of the straight-lines, grey, "boring" type of Order

[Source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore_talk:Jyggalag#Jyggalag_vs_peryite.3F)

Comment: Although I agree, I can't get behind an answer that's based on a bunch of fans shooting the breeze. There's nothing official about that source.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - true, that source is hardly cannon, but from playing the game you get the idea that Jyggalag represents a kind-of mindless order, like entropy.

Comment: @unclebrad True. That doesn't make sourcing fan speculation into a good answer, though. Your own explanation from personal impression is better quality than passing off some random wiki chatter as a [Source] is! ;)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand(and I unfortunately have no sources for this; this is merely conjecture) Peryite is more or less Order in the form of Bureaucracy; he manages the lesser planes of Oblivion.

Jyggalag is ruler of the PLANE of Order. His whole being is dedicated to Order in and of itself, while Peryite simply uses Order as a management tool, trying to make Order from the Chaos that must stem from managing numerous planes of Oblivion.

Hope this at least gives another perspective. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Due to both information gained from Dyus (as well as Dyus's personality) and the descriptions of Peryite as a 'Taskmaster,' I believe the difference to be as so:

Jyggalag represents the concept of predeterminism and the ideas of logical prediction and a sort of Holmesian Deduction (different from Herma-Mora, who keeps ancient and secret knowledge).

Peryite represents Order in the sense of the managing and 'ordering' of the different daedra (as the Prince of Pestilence, he might be described as head of the 'dirty work' in the Planes of Oblivion).

In this sense, you could differentiate the two be saying that Peryite keeps order among the daedra while Jyggalag maintains Order in general.

Answer (score 0):

Actually peruite is of order as is jyggalag.
If you play Oblivion, after serving peryite the worshippers will all say " our work must be put towards prayer so perfect order can be achieved". Meaning peryite is of order just like jyggalag